# ElasticSearch: Backend Closed Connection?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I previously ran a search in Kibana and found out that there are about 1600 unique values in a field called "sensor" over the 12 billion records in a table we have.

Now I want to get a list of the unique values in this field. I ran this in the Kibana console:

```
GET /_search
{
    "size": 2000,
    "aggs" : {
        "distinct_sensor" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "sensor" }
        }
    }
}
```

I got this response back:

```
{
  "ok": false,
  "message": "backend closed connection"
}
```

How can I avoid this error message? Do I need to level up the Kibana server specs?

Comment: What is your search.max_buckets values? More than 2000? Also according to your volume of data, take a loot at composite aggregation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html)

Comment: I tried updating max_buckets to 2000 and got this:# PUT _cluster/settings 200 
#! [xpack.monitoring.collection.node.stats.timeout] setting was deprecated in Elasticsearch and will be removed in a future release.
{
  "acknowledged": true,
  "persistent": {},
  "transient": {
    "search": {
      "max_buckets": "2000"
    }
  }
}